# Error al cambiar el nombre de archivo a .gitignore

Tags: windows, git

Me encuentro migrando de versionador de código, anteriormente usaba Mecurial SCM y ahora estaré usando GIT, el problema viene que Mercurial crea el archivo `.hgignore` para alojar la lista de archivos ignorados pero al intentar renombrarlo para mantener su equivalente en git y tener el `.gitignore` me envía el error:

> You must type a file name (Debe introducir un nombre de archivo válido)

¿Existe alguna forma de renombrar el archivo `.hgignore` y cambiarlo por `.gitignore`?

*Nota: espero encontrar una solución que no involucre instalar alguna herramienta o desarrollar algún tipo de aplicación y el sistema de archivos es Windows.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de cambiarlo es modificando el nombre del archivo y agregando un `.` al final.

En lugar de poner `.gitignore` se debe poner `.gitignore.` y el mismo sistema de archivos quitará el último punto.

<sub>[Respuesta original obtenida de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35246741/3200493)</sub>